# Acessing the dynamic link when the App is in the Background React Native FIrebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

getInitialLink() works when the app is closed and onLink works while the app is running but when the app is backgrounded clicking on the dynamic link is opening the app but when I execute the getInitialLink() once the app becomes active the link with which the app is opened initially is shown not the current one.

EDIT:
I'm currently implementing the App only for iOS

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask" Try adding it in Manifest.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal do you have any idea how to do the same for iOS?

Comment: Can you please add some code on how you are doing it and some screenshots for us to understand the issue better.

Comment: how did you solve it?